# Is it possible to reorder globals in the back end?

Tags: control-panel, globals

Right now Globals are listed in alpha order in the back end.

I was wondering if it would be possible to reorder them somehow? Maybe when working under Settings > Globals, etc.?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on your field type? A Matrix field can be re-ordered by clicking the + icon in the top/right of the field and dragging it somewhere else...

Comment: In this case I'm referring to the reordering of the global sets themselves (not the field assigned to them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's currently not possible to change the order in the control panel, but we might look into that for a future release.  They are currently set to display alphabetically.

Comment: Are you also considering doing category re-ordering for a particular entry? On one site we are using categories as filters on various pages, and the re-ordering for them has to be done globally.